# Is the squared limit of a function equal to the limit of the squared function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

If $\lim_{x\to c}\frac{P(x)^2}{Q(x)^2}$ exists and equals $\ell\neq0$, can one say that $$\lim_{x\to c}\frac{P(x)^2}{Q(x)^2}=\left(\lim_{x\to c}\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\right)^2?$$

My intuition is that one can, since $$\ell=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{P(x)^2}{Q(x)^2}=\left(\lim_{x\to c}\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\right)\left(\lim_{x\to c}\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\right)=\left(\lim_{x\to c}\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\right)^2$$ which seems quite elementary, but I don't know if I need to demonstrate that $\lim_{x\to c}P(x)/Q(x)$ exists. You never know with limits...

Comment: In general it is true that if $f(x)$ is continuous, then $\lim f(g(x)) = f \left( \lim g(x) \right)$. Your case is just $f(x) = x^2$.

Comment: @Nick: No, you also need $\lim_x g(x)$ to exist. For example take $g(x)=(-1)^x$ ($x$ being an integer) and $x\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true in general. Put $Q (x) = 1$ and $P (x)= 1$ if $x$ is rational and $P (x) = -1$ if $x$ is irrational.

You are correct in that the problem is that the nonsquared limit need not exist.

Comment: Could you explain your example a little bit more?

Comment: @user6874652: $P^2(x)/Q^2(x)=1$, but $P(x)/Q(x)=\pm 1$ depending on if $x$ is rational or irrational. So any limit of the latter would oscillate, and hence not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally not true. For example, take L'Hopital's rule, where you take the derivative of both the top and the bottom functions if it is in indeterminate form. If you pull out the exponent, then the answer would be different from if you used L'hopital's rule, the correct way to find the limit.